# How to configure both plain text & JSON file loggers with adjustable log levels for each?

Tags: quarkus

Currently we are logging to files via both the standard Quarkus JBoss Log Manager (which is plain text) and we are using the io.quarkiverse.logging.logback:quarkus-logging-logback extension to configure Logback to generate JSON file based logging.  The problem with this approach is that the extension uses 100% build time configuration settings.  We need to adjust the log settings for both the plain text and JSON file loggers at runtime.  Currently we can only adjust the plain text log levels at runtime.

If I am wrong on the above, please let me know, but that is the 'bug' in our software I was assigned to fix.

I am wondering if I can replace io.quarkiverse.logging.logback:quarkus-logging-logback with io.quarkus:quarkus-logging-json which adds JSON support to the Quarkus JBoss Log Manager.  However how can I configure this to effectively have multiple loggers, one using plain text and one using JSON format?  The documentation https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#json-logging does not show how to do this.  However can I have 'named' file loggers?  Or do File Handlers support the json true/false option?  Or is there another way to accomplish this?

In summary, I am trying to have two different file loggers, one plain text & one JSON and I need to be able to configure the log levels of each at runtime.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76716479/how-to-configure-both-plain-text-json-file-loggers-with-adjustable-log-levels

My research and testing shows this is not currently possible with Quarkus.  I created the following enhancement ticket.  https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/34957